# getting filenotfoundexception while sending json data using java

Tags: java, json

I am trying to send json data to Influx db using following code:

```
String url = "http://xx.x.xx.xx:8086/db/monitoring/check_1113?u=root&p=root";

URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setDoOutput(true);

conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");

//String userpass = "user" + ":" + "pass";
//String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes("UTF-8"));
//conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);

//String data =  "{\"format\":\"json\",\"pattern\":\"#\"}";
System.out.println("Data to send: "+"[{\"name\": \"check_222\",\"columns\": [\"time\", \"sequence_number\", \"value\"],\"points\": [["+unixTime+", 1, \"122\"]]}]");
String data = "[{\"name\": \"check_333\",\"columns\": [\"time\", \"sequence_number\", \"value\"],\"points\": [["+14444444444+", 1, \"122\"]]}]";

OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
out.write(data);
out.close();

new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());   

System.out.println("Data Sent");
```

Where xx.xx.xx.xx is the ip of server where influx is deployed and i am using the Ip.

When i do a manual curl with this data (on localhost), the data is sent successfully. curl is provided below:

```
curl -X POST -d '[{"name": "check_223","columns": ["time", "sequence_number", "value"],"points": [[1445271004000,1,70.8880519867]]}]' 'http://localhost:8086/db/monitoring/series?u=root&p=root'
```

But when I run the code to send the data via the java program shared above, i get following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://xx.x.xx.xx:8086/db/monitoring/check_1113?u=root&p=root
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1834)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
at com.snapdeal.hadoop.monitoring.hdfs1.App.sendJsonDataToInflux(App.java:52)
at com.snapdeal.hadoop.monitoring.hdfs1.App.main(App.java:89)
[INFO  - 2015-10-20T16:27:13.152Z] ShutdownReqHand - _handle - About to shutdown
```

And to add to it, I am using phantomJS to get the data from web page and pass that data in the JSON request. But for simplicity I have hard-coded it at present.

Comment: Did some debugging and found that the URL was not correct. Corrected it and ran the program again. THe FileNOtFound error is gone but i am getting 405 error now which is shown below.

java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be relatively obvious.  A 405 indicates that the HTTP Method on the request is not supported by the endpoint.  The service you are calling does not support a PUT method.

Comment: thanks. I just changed the request method to post and i worked.